# Не сохраняются данные из формы в базу на Django

Tags: django

Добрый день, друзья. Осваиваю Django, не могу сохранить данные из формы в базу данных. Привожу коды:
views.py

```
def Loging(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
      form = PeopleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
              form.cleaned_data()
              form.save()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('index.html')
else:
    form = PeopleForm()
    return render(request,'main.html',locals())
```

forms.py

```
class PeopleForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = People
    fields = ['name','number','adress','email']
```

models.py

```
class People(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=180)
number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
adress = models.CharField(max_length=180)
email = models.EmailField(blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^',views.Loging,name='telefon')
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что отрабатывает form.is_valid() ?

Comment: Нет, а как просмотреть errors?

Comment: После заполнения формы вас перенаправляет на index.html ?

Comment: А, понял! Сейчас изменю проверю.Спасибо

Comment: У вас должна быть предусмотрена какая-то логика, на тот счёт, если form.is_valid вернёт false.

Comment: Я добавил условие на случай не валидности формы: else: return HttpResponseRedirect('main.html'), но увы пока толку не добился, меня не перебрасывает ни на одну из страниц и данных в базе нет(

Comment: Уверены ли, что посылаете POST запрос ?

Comment: Проверяйте каждый из этапов, при помощи print(). Я делаю именно так.
Выводите себе в консоль результат каждого этапа, чтобы понять, где процесс идёт не так, как вам хотелось бы.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, получилось, ошибка была в том, что я в html-шаблоне указывал в metod="" имя вьюхи, которая обрабатывает форму ... Спасибо, за помощь, ваши комментарии были очень полезны)